# Using JavaScript Object Oriented Approach to Validate Form

Tags: javascript, validation

I have been trying to use JS OOP to do form validation; I tested the code in Firefox and chrome :both browsers were just frozen. they did not submit regardless of whether or not the inputs matched the prescribed regular expression. So, who knows where I got it wrong? Pls: I know jQuery validator exists and I can also use plain JS to go as far as circumstances permit. Here, my interest is connecting JS OOP to the DOM. Blogs and textbooks I have read so far have not really shown me how to connect jS OOP to DOM scripting.So, I am just scavenging through rubble, looking for my way out.This code has taken a toll on my battery so I decided to share it here.

```html
<form method = 'post' action ='somewhere.com' onsubmit = 'return formApp.validateInputs.apply(formApp);'>
<p>
Name: <input type = 'text' name = 'userName' id = 'userName'>
</p>
<p>
Phone: <input type = 'text' name = 'userPhone' id = 'userPhone'>
</p>
<input type = 'submit' id = 'sub' value = 'Submit Data'>
</form>
```

```js
var formApp = {
    userNameReg: /[a-z0-9 ' _ ]+/gi,
    onlySpaceReg: /\s+/,
    phoneReg: /\d{3}/,
    userName: document.getElementById('userName').value,
    userPhone: document.getElementById('userPhone').value,
    error: [],
    reportError: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.error.length; i++) {
            alert(this.error[i] + '\n')
        }
    },
    validateInputs: function () {
        if (!this.userNameReg.test(this.userName) || this.onlySpaceReg.test(this.userName)) {
            this.error.push['Name contains illegal character'];
            return false
        } // end name validation

        if (!this.phoneReg.test(this.userPhone)) {
            this.error.push['Only a three-digit number'];
            return false;
        } // end phone validation

        if (this.error.length > 0) {
            this.reportError();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    } // end validateInputs
}; // end formApp obj
```

Comment: why `formApp.validateInputs.apply(formApp);`? Why the apply?
What does the debugger say?

Comment: Just an important FYI regarding Javascript validation.  It should not be relied upon for ensuring that user input is valid.  It is far too easy to bypass (turning javascript off, using a non-javascript client such as curl, etc).  If you have javascript based validation it should be considered a usability aid rather than a security feature and the actual validation of the input must still be done server side.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that you will never get an alert, because you return from the function in all the if blocks where you add an error. So the "this.reportError();" can never be executed. Remove the "return false" statements from ifs.

```
validateInputs: function () {
  if (!this.userNameReg.test(this.userName) || this.onlySpaceReg.test(this.userName)) {
    this.error.push['Name contains illegal character'];
  }// end name validation
  if (!this.phoneReg.test(this.userPhone)) {
    this.error.push['Only a three-digit number'];
  }// end phone validation
  if (this.error.length > 0) {
    this.reportError();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```